# Is there any way to send output of a program to another program in addition to STDOUT?

Tags: bash

I want to pipe the output of a program to another program in addition to STDOUT. The way I am doing it right now is to `tee` the output to a temporary file that I then delete but would be interested in knowing about better approaches where I don't have to create a temp file. Here is my code that shows what I am doing right now:

```
random=`echo $RANDOM`
filename='/tmp/'$random
foo | tee $filename
cat $filename | bar
rm $filename
```

In above `foo` and `bar` are my programs. What I want is to pipe the output of `foo` to `bar` but also have `foo` display its output to STDOUT. If I just do:

```
foo | bar
```

the output to STDOUT is lost.

Comment: have tee write to the process's console instead of a temp file? e.g. `foo | tee /dev/tty | bar`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
foo | tee >(bar)
```

the `>(…)` syntax is for taking the bytes written to "this file" and giving them to the inner process

Answer (score 0):

foo can contain:

```
Message = $message ./bar.sh
```

bar can contain:

```
echo I received the \"$message"\
```